# Moment returns invalid data even though date is correct

Tags: momentjs

I have the following code

```js
var value = 1504528441;
var utcDateTime = moment.utc(value, "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss")
```

and I get `Invalid date`.

I tried converting this number on https://www.epochconverter.com/ and it seems to be converting just fine.

I don't understand what is the problem with moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method and confusing between parsing input and showing moment object value.

There is no `moment.utc(Number, String)` and [`moment.utc(Number)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/) creates a moment object treating `Number` input parameter as *milliseconds* since the Unix Epoch (Jan 1 1970 12AM UTC).

You have to use [`moment.unix(Number)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/unix-timestamp/) since your `value` input is seconds since Unix epoch:

> To create a moment from a Unix timestamp (*seconds* since the Unix Epoch), use `moment.unix(Number)`.

Then you can use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to show the value of your moment object in the format you prefer (e.g. `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"`).

Here a working sample:

```js
var value = 1504528441;
var utcDateTime = moment.unix(value);
console.log( utcDateTime.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss") );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```